# Referring to coordinates of a 3d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, coordinate

In Matlab I'm trying to find points in  a 3d matrix whose coordinates are smaller than some function.
If these coordinates are equal to some functions than I can write:

```
A(some_function1,some_function2,some_function3)=2;
```

But what if I want to do something like:

```
A(<some_function1,<some_function2,<some_function3)=2;
```

This isn't working - so what is the other way of finding such points without using "for" loop? Unfortunately with "for" loop my code takes a lot of time to compute. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this a math question or a code question? I can't tell. Please be specific and what calculation you are trying to do, what code you have tried and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: It is of course a code question. Somehow while writing this post it was co obvious to me, that I forgot to say that it's a Matlab. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of

```
A(  ceil(min(some_function1,size(A,1))),...
    ceil(min(some_function2,size(A,2))),...
    ceil(min(some_function3,size(A,3)))   );
```

This will cap the indicies to the end of each array dimension

Comment: You should ensure that the `some_function*()` returns an integer if you want to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use regular indexing to achieve this:

```
A(1:floor(some_function1),1:floor(some_function2),1:floor(some_function3)) = 2;
```

assuming you check / ensure that `floor(some_function*)` is smaller than the dimensions of `A`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
A(1:size(A,1)<some_function1, 1:size(A,2)<some_function2, 1:size(A,3)<some_function3) = 2
```

I hope I got your question correctly.